# Is there anyway to block http on port 443 using ufw

Tags: 19.10, firewall, ufw

How can I configure ufw so that it blocks any connection to port 443 using the http protocol, but not the https protocol. So what I mean is:

http://example.com:443 (Deny any connection)
https://example.com:443 (Allow any connection)

Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks in advance!

### Edit:

If there is any other program for doing this, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Your webserver should respond to all non-https requests on port 443 with a 400-series error response (Example: 403-Forbidden). If not, then your webserver is misconfigured and should be fixed. Firewall filtering should not be necessary.

Comment: If you are doing this for security reason, then you don't need to do that. If a user connects to any unencrypted port (even 443), they will not see the green padlock or https. So nothing to worry about!

Answer (score 1):

This just an opinion until you get another valid answer.

```
$ sudo ufw deny port/protocol
```

is the typical command for `ufw` but

```
$ sudo ufw deny 443/http
```

gives

```
ERROR: Bad port
```

And

```
$ sudo ufw deny http
$ sudo ufw status
  Status: active
--
80/tcp                     DENY       Anywhere
--
```

Now my guess is that `ufw` only works on the Transport layer. In that layer you can access port numbers, transport layer protocols like TCP/UDP, and of course the IP addresses. And `ufw` is capable of working with those. But http/https is on session layer, one layer lower than transport layer and `ufw` does not have access to those.
But there are other firewalls that work on different layer according to [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/how-to-know-at-what-osi-layers-does-a-firewall-operate)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP uses Port 80, HTTPS is using Port 443.
Therefore, you can't block HTTP by filtering Port 443/TCP.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. "```HTTP uses Port 80, HTTPS is using Port 443```", Well not necessarily. You can use HTTPS on any port you want !!! 443 is just a convention